# XPath base query to return the element within a tag/ the max length in value

Tags: xml, xpath, sed, grep, xmlstarlet

**XPath base query to return the element within a tag/ the max length in value
=============================================================================**

We have large XML data file. XMLSPY is not able to open this file.

Given a list of elements containing text:

```
<root>
     <Person>
  <AttachText>text text text ...</AttachText>
  <AttachText>text text text ...</AttachText>
</Person>
</root>
```

I like to find out whether data exist for AttachText element and it size/length.

I tried with Grep/Sed in Linux, but I did not get desired result.

I'm not sure how to accomplish it. I like to pick up the brain of this forum for some ideas.

Thank in helping.

**Is it possible to use xmlstarlet to get the result?**

Comment: change your `large-files` tag to `xmlstarlet` and search here on same. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might try [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk -F"[<>]" '$3 {print $3,length($3)}' file
```

Comment: I like to understand your solution better. Could you explain your solution with example?

Comment: I tested with this. It list at individual element level. It is not listing at <AttachText> as group counting all nodes within <AttachText>.